# very simple sqlite query "no such column"

Tags: android, sqlite

This should be a very simple task, but i have been stuck for an hour.

I tried this query in the **sqlite browser**, and its **WORKING** :

```
SELECT name FROM msUser WHERE username='admin' AND password='admin'
```

But when i tried this in the Java code, its not wokring :

```
querySelect = "SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE username = " + username + " AND password = " + password;
```

This is what the log cat said :

```
01-19 14:21:02.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3117): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: admin: , while compiling: SELECT name FROM msUser WHERE username = admin AND password = admin
```

Please help me, Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
querySelect = "SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password +"'";
```

Comment: THANKS MAN ITS WORKING!
But..wait, i have been working with sqlite before, and its alright not to add ''. Can you explain whats going on here?

Comment: And please wait, i cant accept your answer, the system said to wait 4 minutes :D

Comment: Look closely at the query. '' not necessary if you use numeric data as parameter, but your username and password are character type. P.S. Try avoid using injection of arguments to the query. Use parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what do you mean by "injection"?Can you give me an example that not using "injection"? Thanks :D

Comment: It depends to your data access provider. What are you use?

Comment: Do you mean its something like db.rawQuery? :D
Sorry for asking much question :D